# Jquery to Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Trying to get this (simple!) jQuery expression to work in Mootools

Jquery:

```
    checkCurrentModule = function(){
        jQuery(".module ul li.current").prepend("<b class='arrow'></b>");
    };
```

And here is my attempt at it in Mootools

```
    var checkCurrentModule = function(){
            var injectModuleli = $$("li.current");
            var currentArrow = new Element("<b class='arrow'></b>");
            currentArrow.inject(injectModuleli);
        };
```

Comment: but whats the problem? do you get any error-messages? script-errors? everything is ok and you just wanted to show how this works? some more information would be really nice...

Comment: jQuery is superior to everything else out there. It shorted my code, accelerated my completion time and cured my dandruff. It cannot be converted, but can only be degraded. You heretic.

Comment: I understand I would rather be doing this in jQuery but when you have a client that doesn't want to add the library then your kinda sol. @oezi I'm trying to get the "valid/working" jQ statement to work in Mootools. I can't seem to get the Mootools statement to "prepend" like I have in my JQ statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var injectModuleli = document.getElement('li.current');
var currentArrow = Elements.from('<strong class="arrow"></strong>');
currentArrow.inject(injectModuleli, 'top');
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/NGjgV/**

Comment: Thanks Oskar, but I noticed in your fiddle that you have the "more" package selected with Mootools. Do you know the specific features I would need to have the about call work?

Answer (score 5):

To provide a solution as one-liner and with no dependency to mootools-more:

```
$$('li.current').grab(new Element('b.arrow'), 'top');
```

(I would just have added this as a comment, but i am not yet allowed to.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with mootools, but I believe the following code does what you want:

```
var checkCurrentModule = function() {
    new Element("b", {
        "class": "arrow"
    }).inject($$(".module ul li.current"), "top");
};
```

Comment: I thought this was going to work but it seems that its actually removing the whole "li.current", then not injecting anything... Which is odd.

Comment: @Starboy, right, it looks like the two elements should be switched. One more thing I learned about mootools :) I'll update my answer.